# Serve a wicket page as PDF

Tags: htmlunit, wicket-6, shieldui, xhtml2pdf

Is there any way for serving an apache wicket page as a PDF?

I need to expert am HTML page to PDF. This page was build using apache wicket and contains charts generated using shieldUI.

I tried to retrieve its content using html unit but quality is very poor.

Thanks,

Laura

Answer (score 3):

The best result you will get if you use the browser's "File > Print > Print to file > PDF" functionality.

If you need to do it with code then you can try with the FlyingSaucer HTML2PDF library.

Comment: The way to do it is: File > Print > Print to file > PDF. I have it both in Google Chrome and Firefox (Linux versions, if this matters). I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Shield UI Chart is rendered in SVG. So you can use any SVG to PDF conversion library for javascript and do the work.

One library I just digget out from Google is:

https://github.com/CBiX/svgToPdf.js/